# EfCore bind method to queryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, include, iqueryable

I would like to stack some methods
this is what I try to do

```
    private static IQueryable<User> IncludeGroup(this IQueryable<User> query)
        => query.Include(d => d.group);
```

I would like to avoid having to do this

```
IncludeGroup(_context.users);
```

Of corse this is a small example my objectif would be to stack some group of includes which would be some times called

Comment: Re-readed your question several times and do not understand what is exactly needed.

Comment: I would like to do this `_context.users.includeGroup()`

Comment: Probably you need extension method. If you want to make extension method, class which contains `IncludeGroup` should be static, `public static class IncludeExtesnions { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.AutoInclude()` in the `OnModelCreating` to configure the model for auto include like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().Navigation(e => e.Prop).AutoInclude();
```